# What kind of WPF composition would I need to implement a two way node diagram?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, telerik, treenode, flowchart

I shall create a visual component to display and navigate a large network of nodes. Nodes have input terminals and output terminals. The total network is too large to be displayed on a single screen.

I see that GUI component vendors have visio-like flowchart/diagramming components for free form placement. It's not exactly what I am looking for. The output should look flowchart-ish, but the functionality is more of a bunch of listboxes / stackpanel / treeview control. I suppose I could make this into a grid or something so that everything should reposition itself dynamically as the user navigates and expand sections, but it is unclear to me how I would then make the connection lines "follow" the item that it is connected to. The nodes are of various types, so there should absolutely be some kind of visual template selection (like datatemplate).

I assume that the topic of visualizing interconnected nodes is a general problem. I've also learned that WPF layout panels are powerful if you apply them correctly, so I am hoping somebody who are more versed in their functionality will be able to break it down into a sensible composition of controls.

BTW I have the Telerik UI RadControls for WPF.

**Do you have any tips or solution for how this functionality can be achieved by composing WPF (and/or Telerik) controls?**

[image: Connection diagram sketch]

Comment: IS there solution for answer?